# Strategy for getting href link from HTML table

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, xpath

My web scraper searches return varying numbers of tablerows, and I am not used to dealing with tables. These tables are 3 columns each. I check to see if the street number in the first column is correct. If it is, then I need to get the link out of the third column of that row. Any thoughts on it? My  code obviously doesn't work, but should give an idea of what I'm trying to do. My code currently doesn't deal with data row by row, only td by td.

What my ideal code would look like:

1. Grabs first table row
2. Checks if street # in first column matches
3. If # matches, grab the link in the third column
4. If # doesn't match, move to check next table row

I'm still EXTREMELY new to programming, so my code is on the clunky simplistic (but poorly written) side still.

HTML in question

```
<tr>
  <td class="transactionTableBodyText">5250 S RAINBOW BLVD 1001  </td>
  <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">SPRING VALLEY</td>
  <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">
    <a id="DataGrid1__ctl3_HyperLink2" href="http://Sandgate.co.clark.nv.us/AssrRealProp/ParcelDetail.aspx?hdnParcel=16326214001&amp;hdnInstance=pcl7" target="_self">163-26-214-001</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My Pythonic Selenium code.

```
td = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.transactionTableBodyText")
    i = 0
    while i <= len(td):
        try:
            if StrtNum in td[i].text:
                print("We matched %s!" % (StrtNum))

                #This is the incorrect part where I try to get to the 'a' selector in the 3rd column from the correctly identified 1st column.
                ParcelLink = td[i+2].driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
                print(ParcelLink)
            else:
                return
        except:
            break
        i+=1
```

Comment: Take a look at Beautiful Soup  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Most of my initial web scraping experiments were done with BS4. I've been using Selenium because of the heavy JS use on the page in question. I'll see if I can use BS4 to deal with what I'm struggling with. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another string for your bow: **lxml**. It gives you access to xpath expressions which can simplify the job of navigating HTML.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(open('sample.htm').read(), parser)
>>> for td in tree.xpath('.//table/tr/td[@class="transactionTableBodyText"][1]'):
...     if td.text.startswith('5250'):
...         tr = td.getparent()
...         td_3_link = tr.xpath('./td[3]/a')
...         link = td_3_link[0].attrib['href']
... 
>>> link
'http://Sandgate.co.clark.nv.us/AssrRealProp/ParcelDetail.aspx?hdnParcel=16326214001&hdnInstance=pcl7'
```

As you can see, I make use of a REPL environment so that I can experiment with various approaches as I try to converge on something that works well and seems reasonably robust.

Almost forgot, this is the HTML I was parsing.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText">1000 S RAINBOW BLVD 1001  </td>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">SPRING VALLEY</td>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">
        <a id="DataGrid1__ctl3_HyperLink2" href="http://Sandgate.co.clark.nv.us/AssrRealProp/ParcelDetail.aspx?hdnParcel=16326214001&amp;hdnInstance=pcl7" target="_self">163-26-214-001</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText">5250 S RAINBOW BLVD 1001  </td>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">SPRING VALLEY</td>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">
        <a id="DataGrid1__ctl3_HyperLink2" href="http://Sandgate.co.clark.nv.us/AssrRealProp/ParcelDetail.aspx?hdnParcel=16326214001&amp;hdnInstance=pcl7" target="_self">163-26-214-001</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText">2000 S RAINBOW BLVD 1001  </td>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">SPRING VALLEY</td>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">
        <a id="DataGrid1__ctl3_HyperLink2" href="http://Sandgate.co.clark.nv.us/AssrRealProp/ParcelDetail.aspx?hdnParcel=16326214001&amp;hdnInstance=pcl7" target="_self">163-26-214-001</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText">2000 S RAINBOW BLVD 1001  </td>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">SPRING VALLEY</td>
      <td class="transactionTableBodyText" align="center">
        <a id="DataGrid1__ctl3_HyperLink2" href="http://Sandgate.co.clark.nv.us/AssrRealProp/ParcelDetail.aspx?hdnParcel=16326214001&amp;hdnInstance=pcl7" target="_self">163-26-214-001</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>'''
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'll take a look at this. I know I'll have to built a more robust/less fragile system for future projects too.